# Accessing public ESXi host behind pfSense LAN

Tags: vmware-esxi, nat, port-forwarding, pfsense

Currently, I have purchased a dedicated ESXi host and spun up a VM running pfSense. I've configured both WAN and LAN through separate vSwitches.

ESXi

- 1.1.1.10 (public IP)

pfSense

- WAN -> 1.1.1.20/32 (public IP)
- LAN -> 192.168.1.0/24

I've then created a Windows VM and looking to manage the ESXi host from it.
Windows host has an IP address of 192.168.1.1 and a 1:1 NAT set up in pfSense (Public: 1.1.1.30)
I'm however having some trouble in accessing the web GUI for the ESXi host within this VM (no ping response and traceroute only goes to pfSense server).

Within pfSense, I've tried enabling 'NAT Reflection mode for port forwards' and set to Pure NAT (as I've read this should help with NAT hairpinning) but my knowledge on pfSense is limited on how to get this working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Kev

Comment: Did you create a virtual adapter for your 1:1 NAT?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can access your Windows VM or not. If you can't then on pfsense you need to go to firewall > NAT and configure like below

[image]

You should also check your firewall rules like below

[image]

When you can RD your Windows VM then you should check if your LAN is on the same virtual switch which has your VM kernel port.